# Extract all links from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I have a javascript variable containing the HTML source code of a page (not the source of the current page), I need to extract all links from this variable.
Any clues as to what's the best way of doing this?

Is it possible to create a DOM for the HTML in the variable and then walk that?

Comment: I think your best approach will be using some kind of JS HTML document parser. Alternatively you could use regular expressions, but I don't think that's the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know if this is the recommended way, but it works: (JavaScript only)

```
var rawHTML = '<html><body><a href="foo">bar</a><a href="narf">zort</a></body></html>';

var doc = document.createElement("html");
doc.innerHTML = rawHTML;
var links = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
var urls = [];

for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    urls.push(links[i].getAttribute("href"));
}
alert(urls)
```

Comment: If in node, this answer can be extended with JSDOM: `const { JSDOM } = jsdom;`
   `const dom = new JSDOM(rawHTML);`
   `const { document: doc } = dom.window;` then skip to `var links = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")`

Answer (score 7):

If you're using jQuery, you can really easily I believe:

```
var doc = $(rawHTML);
var links = $('a', doc);
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#htmlownerDocument

Answer (score 2):

This is useful esepcially if you need to replace links...

```
var linkReg = /(<[Aa]\s(.*)<\/[Aa]>)/g;

var linksInText = text.match(linkReg);
```

Comment: When I tested this with this HTML string `var text = '<html><body><a href="foo">bar</a><div>dfgdfg</div> ghghhkhkh<a href="narf">zort</a></body></html>';`  It returned the whole HTML text string and not just matches for A links

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Firefox YES YOU CAN ! It's called [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser) , check it out:

```
DOMParser is mainly useful for applications and extensions based on Mozilla platform. While it's available to web pages, it's not part of any standard and level of support in other browsers is unknown.
```

Comment: "YES YOU CAN!" What is this? Bob the Builder? :P

Comment: :) Yes , it's bob the builder

Comment: Love this answer. It seems 2009 was still the golden age for websites `Optimized for [Broswer name] - [Browser version]`

Answer (score 1):

If you are running outside a browser context and don't want to pull a HTML parser dependency, here's a naive approach:

```js
var html = `
<html><body>
  <a href="https://example.com">Example</a>
  <p>text</p>
  <a download href='./doc.pdf'>Download</a>
</body></html>`

var anchors = /<a\s[^>]*?href=(["']?)([^\s]+?)\1[^>]*?>/ig;
var links = [];
html.replace(anchors, function (_anchor, _quote, url) {
  links.push(url);
});

console.log(links);
```